# What is a parameter in Bayesian analysis?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, parameter-estimation

In any case study, when we use Bayesian analysis to solve our problem we consider a model parameter which is sometimes known and sometimes unknown. And using this parameter(and of course prior data) we construct prior and posterior distributions for our model.

Can someone explain to me by giving example/s (may be a case study) what actually is this model parameter? What are its properties?

Comment: I would say that you build a model including an unknown parameter of interest. Starting with a prior distribution for that parameter, you make observations and combine the likelihood from the observations with the prior to produce a posterior distribution for the parameter, all within the context of your model.  You could describe the parameter as a value in your model, with the properties you give it.

Comment: A situation with binomial data and a beta-distributed prior is fairly simple and may help answer your question. Perhaps search this site for 'Bayesian beta binomial' and browse some of the pages fetched. I answered one of them `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288430/` and would try to answer related questions.